# spring message header: DestinationResolver is required to resolve destination names

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a question about spring `TcpOutboundGateway` and `Message` configuration.

I need to send a tcp message via tcp outbound gateway and in fact I don't need to have it like a Bean, I want to create it each time when I need to send a message. I want to use strictly a gateway since I want to receive an answer as well:

```
//objects clientConnectionFactory and receiveChannel are created above
TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
tcpOutboundGateway.setRequiresReply(true);
tcpOutboundGateway.setReplyChannel(receiveChannel);
tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(10000);
tcpOutboundGateway.setSendTimeout(10000);
```

Then I send a message via the gateway:

```
MessageBuilder<byte[]> mb = MessageBuilder.withPayload(myBytes);
//I need to set this header, otherwise I receive an exception 
//no output-channel or replyChannel header available
mb.setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, "receiveChannel");
Message<byte[]> message = mb.build();

clientConnectionFactory.start();
tcpOutboundGateway.handleMessage(message);
clientConnectionFactory.stop();
```

And then I receive the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DestinationResolver is required to resolve destination names
```

I think something is wrong with this message header but I cannot understand what. Do you know, how could I set it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create it each time when I need to send a message.

That seems a little excessive; it's not really clear why you are using the Spring Integration bits for an application like that.

If you explain your use case, someone might be able to provide a better solution.

That said...

```
//I need to set this header, otherwise I receive an exception 
//no output-channel or replyChannel header available
mb.setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, "receiveChannel");
```

Setting it to a `String` is why the resolver is needed; it has to be a channel or a resolver available to resolve it to a channel.

You don't have to set in in a header, you can use

```
QueueChannel channel = new QueueChannel();
tcpOutboundGateway.setOutputChannel(channel();
...
Message<?> = channel.receive(TIMEOUT);
```

You only need a `replyChannel` header if there's no `outputChannel` property.

Comment: How do I need to set this header correcly? 
if I write `mb.setHeader(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, receiveChannel);` I get "no output-channel or replyChannel header available"-Exception again

Comment: I have set an output channel, it still sends "no output-channel or replyChannel header available"-Exception if there is no header for message

Comment: You must be mistaken; that exception is only thrown if the `outputChannel` property is `null`; only then do we look for a channel in the `replyChannel` header.